# How to use SQL function that returns a table in Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, t-sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a T-SQL database function that returns a table output. I can query it in raw SQL simply:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.myTableFunction(param1, param2)
```

I've tried following the solution here:

[How do I call a database function using SQLAlchemy in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878846/how-do-i-call-a-database-function-using-sqlalchemy-in-flask)

My Python code looks as follows:

```
db.session.query(func.dbo.myTableFunction(param1, param2)).all()
```

However I'm getting an error:

> [SQL Server]Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.myTableFunction", or the name is ambiguous.
> (4121) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)')
> [SQL: SELECT dbo.myTableFunction(?, ?) AS myTableFunction_1]

I can see that the SQL statement is clearly incorrect but I don't know how to correct it. I'm expecting a SQL statement similar to the raw SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.myTableFunction(param1, param2)
```

But I'm unsure of how to achieve this using Flask-SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. To call a function with a table output, use:

```
db.session.query(
    select([column("col_1"), column("col_2")])
    .select_from(func.dbo.myTableFunction(param1, param2).alias()).subquery()
)
```

where "col_1" and "col_2" are the names of the columns being returned from the function